# How to change color of FxIconics label using css, when onselect action is performed?

Tags: javafx, colors, label, font-awesome, tabpanel

I have used [Android-Iconics library, developed by Mike Penz](https://github.com/pepperonas/FxIconics) for my Javafx project.

Code:

```
Tab tab1 = new Tab();
FxIconicsLabel labelDefault
                = (FxIconicsLabel) new FxIconicsLabel.Builder(FxFontAwesome.Icons.faw_user)
                .size(18)
                .color(Color.web("#555555"))
                .build();
tab1.setGraphic(labelDefault);
tab1.setText(" Customer");
```

CSS:

```
.tab:selected {
    -fx-border-color: #ddd #ddd #fff #ddd;
    -fx-border-radius: 5 5 0 0;
    -fx-text-fill: #555555;
    -fx-font-weight: bold ;
}
```

I want to change the icon i.e (labelDefault) COLOR using css, when tab is selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you check Oracles [CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for JavaFX, you can see that the TabPane contains a Tab which contains a Label. On the Label you can set the graphics:

```
-fx-graphic: <uri>;
```

It probably might be easiest to define separate classes for the different states of the tab and then assign it to the label.